# Random variable convergence question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Trying to solve the following question. Not sure if it is a trivial question or I am missing something here:

I have a random variable $X$, with:

$P(X=1) = P(X=-1) = 1/2$

Now define $X_n$ as:

$$
    X_n= 
\begin{cases}
    X,& \text{with probability}\ 1-1/n\\
    e^n,              & \text{with probability}\ 1/n
\end{cases}
$$

Does $X_n$ converge to $X$ in probability and distribution? My intuition says yes, as $n$ approaches infinity, $1/n$ will approach $0$ and $X_n=X$. Is this a valid proof?

Thanks!

Comment: For convergence in probability, you may be supposed to say something like $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr\left(|X_n-X| > \varepsilon\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n = 0$.  There are similar statements for convergence in distribution, but in any case  convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution

Comment: Though note that $E[X_n] \not \to E[X]$ and if the events $X_n=e^n$ are independent for different $n$ then I think you do not have almost sure convergence of $X_n$ to $X$